# Is there an API for calling system scripts/programs?

Tags: java, bash, shell, scripting

is there something like API built atop the standard ProcessBuilder for calling system programs? I won't argue that scripts can be ported to Java but utilities like arping and netstat are good-to-go in Linux.

Comment: Is this what the OS does?  Runs scripts and programs? Are you writing an OS?  Or, more importantly, why are you worrying about this?  A shell script is the usual OS interface to run scripts and programs.

Comment: S.Lott: What are you talking about? Where the people at Sun who wrote *Runtime.exec* and *ProcessBuilder* high on dope?  What about the dudes from Apache who wrote *Commons Exec* (the accepted answer)?  Are they all just seeing things or is the OP's question a perfectly legitimate one?  What are you exactly bringing to this discussion with that comment and these questions?  *"Are you writing an OS?"* [sic] is a seriously rude question IMHO.  Thanks for all the help and say hello to Apache and the Sun engineers for me ;)

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: I'm sorry, but the question is brief and confusing.  I regret not being as brilliant as others, but I can't parse the question as written.  I'm trying to understand the question.  Lacking deep insight, I'm forced to ask what the question is about.  Again, I apologize for not being brilliant and insightful.

Comment: *Is there an Java API for calling system scripts/programs from JVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using few projects from Apache commons but I never spotted this one.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the standard [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class... It handles calling scripts pretty well.  Here is a [post showing how this can be used to call a command via bash](http://forums.devx.com/showpost.php?p=517437&postcount=6).

Answer (score 2):

Using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` except you need to know the name and parameters to pass to system program.

Comment: Hi, I was asking for API deliberately because my next work will make heavy use of calling programs and as a part of exploration whether or not to try write one.